# How to get the required value displayed from the given array?

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

From below array i want the value of "_sql" to be displayed or we can I want to echo the "_sql" value, so what should be the syntax to display it in PHP code?

```
JTableMenu Object
(
    [lft] => 
    [rgt] => 
    [home] => 
    [_tbl] => #__menu
    [_tbl_key] => id
    [_db] => JDatabaseMySQL Object
        (
            [name] => mysql
            [_nullDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [_nameQuote] => `
            [_sql] => INSERT INTO `jos_menu` ( `id`,`menutype`,`name`,`alias`,`link`,`type`,`published`,`componentid`,`parent`,`ordering`,`checked_out`,`checked_out_time`,`brow............
            [_errorNum] => 0
         )
)
```

In the code the above array is stored in $row, so i have written an echo statement to display the required value like this: `echo $row['_db]['_sql'];` please suggest where and why I am getting wrong Why I cannot get the value in "_sql" index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Solution I did this

```
echo $row->_db->_sql;
```

And I got the output...
Thanks Pranav

Comment: it would be cleaner OOP to have getter methods for this.